# How can I convert a multi-dictionary to proper JSON structure?

Tags: python, json

I just have one value for each key, but the JSON structure I am getting, with [ ] for a singe value also. How can I get rid of `[` and `]` in the value to make it a proper JSON structure?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   result = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
   fdf = json.dumps(result)
   print(fdf)
```

Output:

```
"C7Interest Rate": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 PDB": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 Financial Change": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 Liquidity": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 Enhanced Benefits": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 MIO": [
            "None"
        ],
        "C7 GDB": [
            "None"
        ],
```

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with the output.  It is valid JSON.  HTML forms can submit multiple values for a single form field name, and as such, the flask library supports that by placing values in a list to indicate there could be more than one.

Comment: Try to remove flat=False

Comment: @g.d.d.c: I disagree — it's not valid JSON format. However I think trying to fix it anywhere other than at the source is a fool's errand.

Comment: @martineau - I'm pretty sure what they've shown is an excerpt, not the full output.  `to_dict` docs:  https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.to_dict.  If it weren't a valid dictionary `json.dumps` would've choked on producing it.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Perhaps you're correct. The OP should add more information to their question.

Comment: _How can I get rid of `[` and `]` in the value to make it a proper JSON structure?_ The square brackets have actual meaning. Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Comment: @Dolfa Thank you! It worked after removing flat=false

Comment: @samnayak Great, I added it as a anwser, please accept it if you have a chance for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove flat=False

According to Flask documentation:

```
If flat is True the returned dict will only have the first item present, if flat is False all values will be returned as lists.
```

Hope that you are expecting only single values in json, otherwise this could be problematic operation as you might be loosing data as [] is valid json declaration for array, eg. multiple items. With flat=False you will get only first value from a list, you will loose others.